# Executing Jquery ajax function if  sucess ,then call to  other jquery function

Tags: jquery

While executing a Jquery ajax function, if sucess then  call other jquery function which returns value to first function

// JavaScript Document

```
    button = function(first,last) {
    var butVal21  = $('#button21').val();   
    var butVal22  = $('#button22').val();   


    doPost('cross.php',
                    'first=' + first +
                    '&button22=' + butVal22 +
            '&last=' + last,
                   function(response) {

                       if(buttonVal == '') {
                                            $('#button'+first+last).val("X");
                        var status = checkSucess(first,last,'X');
    // I want to status value as return value for checkSucess function.
                        if (status != null) { return false; }

                        console.info(response);

                        }
                    }
        );

    }

    checkSucess = function(first,last,value) {
    doPost('sucess.php',
                    'first=' + first ,

                     function(response) {
                       if(response == 'X') {

                        return 'sucess';
                        }
                       else if(response == 'O') {

                        return 'failure';
                        }

                    }
        );
    }




    }
```

I want to status value as return value for checkSucess function. But not able to do that.
Second I want to stop a jquery function in case : if (status != null) ,is it possible by giving return false

Answer (score 1):

You don't really return values like that from Ajax functions: the Ajax call will happen at an arbitrary time in the future, returning (relatively) long after the call you've made to `checkSuccess()`.

Often [jQuery's `.when()` function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/) can be used to chain multiple Ajax calls together.

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davelnewton/A4FVU/) as an example of chaining Ajax functions. The results of the first Ajax call are passed to the function that makes the second call.

Comment: $.when($.ajax("sucess.php")).then(checkSucess);   how can i pass value to checkSucess method

Comment: The problem  is I want to this while in between of first function for call to second function.       $.when($.ajax("cross.php")).then(function(firstCallResults) {
      console.log(firstCallResults);
      $.when(checkSucess(first,last,'X')).then(function(secondCallResults) {
       console.log(secondCallResults);
      });       
     });

Comment: @Jusnit I don't understand what you're saying. You can put whatever code you want after the first call and before the second, and after the second.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like one possible solution would be to change your doPost call from an asynchronous request to a synchronous one, like so:

```
checkSucess = function(first,last,value) {
    var returnValue = 'failure';

    $.ajax({

        async: false, 

        url:'sucess.php',
        data:'first=' + first ,

        success: function(response) {
                       if(response == 'X') {

                        returnValue = 'sucess';
                        }
                       else if(response == 'O') {

                        returnValue = 'failure';
                        }

                    }
        });
        alert(returnValue);
        return returnValue;
    }
```

Comment: Do you get an error?  I just added an alert - does that get triggered? What does it say?

Comment: When alerting always return 'failure', but when alert inside if (response == 'X') then return 'sucess'.

Comment: It should work...  Check out this fiddle, it demonstrates same basic approach: http://jsfiddle.net/ytRVY/